# Android Studio - How to fix Internal error when trying to read zip file

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner in android studio, I use android studio

## More information

- My device runs on Virtual Device Nexus 5X API 28
- Android studio v. 3.3
- JDK v. 1.8.0
- JRE v. 1.8.0
- Original code (empty project template)

When I run project app from Android Studio

I got the following message in the console.

> Internal error when trying to read zip file 'C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\5a46c076ff7d88cc2aa1f3c86b046c42\jars\classes.jar'.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudioProjects\"ํYour Project Folder"

- Find gradle.properties
- in gradle.properties
- Change org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m to
- org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en
- Save

Comment: I don't know, I tried to find information from community, But did not find the required information, So I tried to solve this problem based on a similar problem, When I fix the problem successfully, So I share it to others who have the same problem as me.

Sorry for my English.