# Getting some unknown error of :app:processDebugResources while flutter run

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Today when I was running my Flutter project I got some unknown error and its solution is not available according to my research. Please tell me if you know how to solve it.
**Before Today, I was not getting any error like this**.
Why it happened today only. Is it due to Gradle update? Is Gradle update is automatic? Please solve my queries.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\Projects\Flutter Zone\CovidTraces\build\path_provider\intermediates\res\symbol-table-with-package\debug\package-aware-r.txt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Thank You:}

Comment: Could you please run `flutter clean && flutter run`?

Comment: @paulsm4 it is a flutter project

Comment: @Alok Yes, I did it but it didn't work for me. Please help I want to proceed and I am such at this point. I am still getting the same error after flutter clean and run.

Comment: Hey @ShîvamYadav it is up to the perspective only. Part of the learning, without downfall, you don't learn to appreciate the heights/success. It is okay. You learnt something, that is the thing you should focusing upon. Thanks for the upvote! Happy learning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to give out certain pointers which you can try and then check it if it works correctly. I am hoping that, the options will work out for you. Just go one by one, and check which one works the best.

> I am going to point out the best solution to normal solution format. So keep a track

**1. Changing classpath**

- Change `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m` to `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en`
- Change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340943/android-studio-how-to-fix-internal-error-when-trying-to-read-zip-file) to know more about it

**2. OR Simply do this**

- Change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`

**3. Removing vector assets**

- Resolve by removing that vector asset file. Please check if you recently made any change to your vector asset file.

**4. Packages caches repair**

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub cache repair`
- `flutter run`